# Why is the Drag n Drop Js breaking the upload process of php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, ecmascript-6

Thank you so much for reading and Answering our question. You see, we have a simple html form the action is linked to php that uploads a file the php is verified in working order the form has the encytype multipart/form-data  with the input type of file, everything works just fine if you choose the file with the button on the form **without** the drag and drop script that follows  We must have the drag and drop feature, we have taken apart the script using it piece by piece the file would upload at once it is a whole it won't run the php and therefor won't work even just clicking the button to add the file won't work. It breaks the whole thing. If you need me to add everything I will but the error must come from this script and not from the other parts as it does work without the script but we can't drag or drop anything Again the Code is as follows 
Starting off with the html ending with the script that breaks it.

```
<div class="container" role="main">
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="box">
<div class="box__input">
            <svg class="box__icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="43" viewBox="0 0 50 43">
                    <path d="M48.4 26.5c-.9 0-1.7.7-1.7 1.7v11.6h-43.3v-11.6c0-.9-.7-1.7-1.7-1.7s-1.7.7-1.7 1.7v13.2c0 .9.7 1.7 1.7 1.7h46.7c.9 0 1.7-.7 1.7-1.7v-13.2c0-1-.7-1.7-1.7-1.7zm-24.5 6.1c.3.3.8.5 1.2.5.4 0 .9-.2 1.2-.5l10-11.6c.7-.7.7-1.7 0-2.4s-1.7-.7-2.4 0l-7.1 8.3v-25.3c0-.9-.7-1.7-1.7-1.7s-1.7.7-1.7 1.7v25.3l-7.1-8.3c-.7-.7-1.7-.7-2.4 0s-.7 1.7 0 2.4l10 11.6z"/>
                </svg>
    <input type="file" name="file" class="box__file">
    <label for="file">
                    <strong>Choose a file</strong>
                    <span class="box__dragndrop">or drag it here</span>
                    .
                </label>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="box__button">
        UPLOAD
    </button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>



     'use strict';

        ;
        (function(document, window, index) {
            // feature detection for drag&drop upload
            var isAdvancedUpload = function() {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                return (('draggable' in div) || ('ondragstart' in div && 'ondrop' in div)) && 'FormData' in window && 'FileReader' in window;
            }();

            // applying the effect for every form
            var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(forms, function(form) {
                var input = form.querySelector('input[type="file"]'),
                    label = form.querySelector('label'),
                    errorMsg = form.querySelector('.box__error span'),
                    restart = form.querySelectorAll('.box__restart'),
                    droppedFiles = false,
                    showFiles = function(files) {
                        label.textContent = files.length > 1 ? (input.getAttribute('data-multiple-caption') || '').replace('{count}', files.length) : files[0].name;
                    },
                    triggerFormSubmit = function() {
                        var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
                        event.initEvent('submit', true, false);
                        form.dispatchEvent(event);
                    };

                // letting the server side to know we are going to make an Ajax request
                var ajaxFlag = document.createElement('input');
                ajaxFlag.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                ajaxFlag.setAttribute('name', 'ajax');
                ajaxFlag.setAttribute('value', 1);
                form.appendChild(ajaxFlag);

                // automatically submit the form on file select
                input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
                    showFiles(e.target.files);

                });

                // drag&drop files if the feature is available
                if (isAdvancedUpload) {
                    form.classList.add('has-advanced-upload');
                    // letting the CSS part to know drag&drop is supported by the browser

                    ['drag', 'dragstart', 'dragend', 'dragover', 'dragenter', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(function(event) {
                        form.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
                            // preventing the unwanted behaviours
                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        });
                    });
                    ['dragover', 'dragenter'].forEach(function(event) {
                        form.addEventListener(event, function() {
                            form.classList.add('is-dragover');
                        });
                    });
                    ['dragleave', 'dragend', 'drop'].forEach(function(event) {
                        form.addEventListener(event, function() {
                            form.classList.remove('is-dragover');
                        });
                    });
                    form.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
                        droppedFiles = e.dataTransfer.files;
                        // the files that were dropped
                        showFiles(droppedFiles);

                    });
                }

                // if the form was submitted
                form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
                    // preventing the duplicate submissions if the current one is in progress
                    if (form.classList.contains('is-uploading'))
                        return false;

                    form.classList.add('is-uploading');
                    form.classList.remove('is-error');

                    if (isAdvancedUpload) // ajax file upload for modern browsers
                    {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        // gathering the form data
                        var ajaxData = new FormData(form);
                        if (droppedFiles) {
                            Array.prototype.forEach.call(droppedFiles, function(file) {
                                ajaxData.append(input.getAttribute('name'), file);
                            });
                        }

                        // ajax request
                        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        ajax.open(form.getAttribute('method'), form.getAttribute('action'), true);

                        ajax.onload = function() {
                            form.classList.remove('is-uploading');
                            if (ajax.status >= 200 && ajax.status < 400) {
                                var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
                                form.classList.add(data.success == true ? 'is-success' : 'is-error');
                                if (!data.success)
                                    errorMsg.textContent = data.error;
                            } else
                                alert('Error. Please, contact the webmaster!');
                        };

                        ajax.onerror = function() {
                            form.classList.remove('is-uploading');
                            alert('Error. Please, try again!');
                        };

                        ajax.send(ajaxData);

 } else // fallback Ajax solution upload for older browsers
                    {
                        var iframeName = 'uploadiframe' + new Date().getTime(),
                            iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

                        $iframe = $('<iframe name="' + iframeName + '" style="display: none;"></iframe>');

                        iframe.setAttribute('name', iframeName);
                        iframe.style.display = 'none';

                        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                        form.setAttribute('target', iframeName);

                        iframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
                            var data = JSON.parse(iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML);
                            form.classList.remove('is-uploading')
                            form.classList.add(data.success == true ? 'is-success' : 'is-error')
                            form.removeAttribute('target');
                            if (!data.success)
                                errorMsg.textContent = data.error;
                            iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
                        });
                    }
                });

                // restart the form if has a state of error/success
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(restart, function(entry) {
                    entry.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        form.classList.remove('is-error', 'is-success');
                        input.click();
                    });
                });
                // Firefox focus bug fix for file input
                input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
                    input.classList.add('has-focus');
                });
                input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
                    input.classList.remove('has-focus');
                });

            });

                        }(document, window, 0));
```

After being requested to run a console.log with `var data = JSON.parse(iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML); console.log("Data: " + data);` for the ajax response, I received the following errors
 Uncaught ReferenceError: iframe is not defined at :1:23 (anonymous) @ VM407:1 2VM408:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.ajax.onload (index.php:367)

index.php line 367 is ` form.classList.add(data.success == true ? 'is-success' : 'is-error');

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I don’t have enough score to comment so I had to type a message here, have you tried logging the contents of your response from the Ajax request in console? From what I can see your form relies on the response and if you aren’t getting a response your error could be in the file your sending to. Maybe you haven’t echo’d json_encode ?

Comment: Posting comments as answers is a great way to lose the little reputation you have gained, instead you should post answers that don't require clarification from the OP until you gain the ability to post comments.

Comment: I have an error log in my php, but as for what you mean I do not know how to do that. Could you leave an example

Comment: it does seem that I have some error being reported in the cosole Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ajax.onload (index.php:367)

Comment: var data = JSON.parse(iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML);
console.log("Data: " + data);

then inspect element and click on console when you have tried to click and drag the image.

Comment: This is what I get here Uncaught ReferenceError: iframe is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:23
(anonymous) @ VM407:1
2VM408:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ajax.onload (index.php:367)

Comment: index.php line 367 is ` form.classList.add(data.success == true ? 'is-success' : 'is-error');`

Comment: @Bama Please include these details in the question itself, otherwise if this answer gets deleted, no-one will be able to see it.